# Laravel Eloquent - Table join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have one problem where I need help. I'm doing one project in learning purposes.

I have 2 tables, the first one is

**USERS** which contain id (PK, AI), username, email, password and so on...

Another table called

**FRIENDS**

contain user_a (FK to users.id), user_b (FK to users.id), status (0 - pending, 1 - confirmed)...

Lets say the current logged user have id 1.

I need to join this 2 tables and get complete friend list for currently logged user, so query trough table friends where user_a or user_b = currently logged user id, and get all data (from table users) for his friend... So lets say this:

user_a = 1, user_b = 2
userb_a = 3, user_b = 1

I need to get info for users 2, 3.

I hope so you understand what I need.

Btw I know how to do this without using Eloquent, but I need to use Eloquent.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post your user model as it is currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is many to many relationship, so you need `belongsToMany`.

```
// basic setup
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friends', 'user_a', 'user_b')
      ->withPivot('confirmed');
}
```

However that's not all, since you want it to be bidirectional. This means you need to setup 2 relationships - **here you can find exact solution for this:**

[Friendship system with Laravel : Many to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship#25057320)

Answer (score 1):

you can form the hasMany() relationship between Users and Friends Table

In User Model You have to write

```
public function friends() {
  return $this->hasMany('Friend','user_a');
}
```

and While fetching the data from the database.

```
$user = User::with('friends')->find($userId);
```

using eager loading you can get all friends of a currently logged in user.

here is a link for relationships in laravel

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but can I use in my User model this: return $this->hasMany('Friend', 'user_a', 'user_b'); since the user_a or user_b can be currently logged user. Is that correct? So basically user_a or user_b can be currently logged in user.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Thanks for bringing it to my attention. :)

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try.  If should give you want you want. Add the ids and emails if you need them.

```
select u.username, f.status, uf.username as friendname
from users u
join friends f on
  f.user_a = u.id or f.user_b = u.id
join users uf on
  uf.id = f.user_a or uf.id = f.user_b
  and uf.id != u.id
```

Comment: OP states that he knows how to do this with SQL, but he needs to be able to do this using Eloquent.

Comment: Ya I stated i know how do to in SQL, but I need to do this using Eloquent. Thanks for a shot anyway.