# Laravel 5.2 Friendship system: Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Table friends: id, user_id, friend_id.

Table user_profiles: id, user_id, first_name...

How to get a list of the user's friends through Eloquent ORM?

user_id: 5 | friend_id: 6

user_id: 6 | friend_id 5

Similar questions:

[Friendship system with Laravel : Many to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship)

[Laravel & Eloquent - Query 'Friends' Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028072/laravel-eloquent-query-friends-relationship)

I can not understand who calls the method getFriendsAttribute().

And how to do it Query builder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define relationship on `User` model:

```
class User extend Model
{
    ...

    // Get list of who sent me a friend request
    public function myFriends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(get_class($this), 'friends', 'friend_id');
    }

    // Get the list of friends whom I invited
    public function friendsOf()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(get_class($this), 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
    }

    // Merge
    public function getFriendsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->myFriends->merge($this->friendOf);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the list of user's friends by `$user->myFriends`, to query friend by their first name: `$user->myFriends()->where('first_name', '=', 'John')->get()`.

Comment: I have a relationship. But I can get a list of only user_id or user_friend. How to combine requests ?

Comment: I didn't get your question about "But I can get a list of only user_id or user_friend. How to combine requests ?" can you please more clear what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Did you meant get friend list by certain `user_id`?

Comment: If I write so:
return $this->belongsToMany(get_class($this), 'users_friends', 'friend_id');
I got those who sent me a friend request/ invitation

If I write so:
return $this->belongsToMany(get_class($this), 'users_friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
I got the list of friends whom I invited. But I am not visible a their friend's list.

Comment: @Anton if you want display both friends who invites you and your invited friends then you can merge those relationship using `merge()`, see edited answer.

Comment: Strangely , I have tried to do so , but it did not work . And now it works! Many thanks!