# Followers / Following and finding who follows Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have my Relation table which goes as following:

```
UserId (PK)
FollowingId
created_at
updated_at
```

I am able to get who the user is following and their usernames by doing the following:

My controller:

```
$findingWhoIFollow = User::find($userId)->relations()->FindUserName()->get();
```

My model (user):

```
public function relations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Relation::class, 'UserId', 'id');
}
```

My model: (relation)

```
protected $primaryKey = 'UserId';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'id', 'UserId');
}
public function scopeFindUserName($query)
{
    return $query->join('User', 'User.id', '=', 'Relation.FollowingId');
}
```

and then i am able to get the usernames of the people I follow like this:

```
@foreach($findingWhoIFollow as $iFollow)
     {{$iFollow->Username}}
@endforeach
```

I am however struggling to do the inverse of this eg: getting the users who follow my accounts user names. I believe it's an issue with my relationships and I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Friendship system with Laravel : Many to Many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by fixing my relationships as per the suggested duplicate Fabio Antunes posted ([Friendship system with Laravel : Many to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship))