# Laravel friendship system, accepting / deleting requests

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

So, I'm trying to get this friendship system to work.
I got it working with relations and such in the User model, and I can grab a collection of a given user or a signed users friends based on the friendship status.

But I haven't created any code for sending, accepting or deleting a friend request.

(The code I use is based on this: [Friendship system with Laravel : Many to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship)

Is it best practice to do this in the Friend model, or should I do this in a controller?

Also, should I consider to put this in the Friend model? Currently it is in the User model. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Friendships
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function friends() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id')
        -> wherePivot('status', '=', 1);
}
```

Comment: As i can see you've three relationship code duplication. ```return $this -> belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id')
        -> wherePivot('status', '=', 1);``` You can add one method and make it generic as u did for the first one by naming it ```friends()```. They should be in User model since each User have multiple friends.

Comment: Oh darn. Thank you. I didn't even realise that. I have minified it down to one method now.

Comment: But would I add the code for checking if two given users are friends `$user -> friends -> contains($user_id)` etc. in the Friend model? Or in the User model?

Comment: Forget about Friend Model. Friendship is relationship. User is a model. When u want get a friend  You expecting 'User object' not 'Friend object'. Friend is only relationship. And yeah you can perform some if statements to check if already friend exists before adding new one.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearifying.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need anything else.